# activate opcache load comments in php 7

Tags: php, symfony, php-7, opcache, php-7.1

I want to migrate a symfony website from php 5.6 to php 7.1.4

I got this error :

```
AnnotationException in AnnotationException.php line 193:
You have to enable opcache.load_comments=1 or zend_optimizerplus.load_comments=1.
```

I my php.ini I already had `opcache.save_comments` set to '1' so I've added `opcache.load_comments=1` in the php.ini but when I see my `phpinfo()` the opcache.load_comments parameter didn't appear ... and if I try :

```
ini_set('opcache.load_comments', 1);
echo "VALUE : " .  ini_get('opcache.load_comments');
```

It doesn't work neither ...

Comment: Did you check that the path to the php.ini in the phpinfo() output is the same file that the one where you did the changes?

Comment: Yes it is the same file.

Comment: And the ini_set('opcache.load_comments', 1); should work because the doc says it can be modify everywhere (PHP_INI_ALL) but it doesn't work ...